# No primary available for writes - PyMongo error

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have been trying to learn Python Mongodb, So I set up an account and tried to run a basic program off the internet.

**My Code:**

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://userxx:passxx@cluster0-bhcn7.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]

mydict = { "name": "John", "address": "Highway 37"}
x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
```

**But I'm getting the error:**

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No primary available for writes`

Any suggestions on rectifying this error are much appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: Ensure your IP address is whitelisted in atlas.

Comment: @Oleg It is whitlisted